# Which RxJava scheduler does doOnDispose() use?

Tags: rx-java2

I have an Rxjava assembly something like this:

```
    val observable = dialogPresenter.show(dialogData, viewContext!!)
            .subscribeOn(mainScheduler)
            .observeOn(mainScheduler)
            .doOnDispose(dialogData::dismiss)
```

When the subscription is disposed, the call to `dialogData::dismiss` is happening on a thread other than that used by `mainScheduler`, which as the name implies uses the main thread for the particular platform the code is running on. The Javadoc for `doOnDispose()` says it does not operate by default on a particular scheduler, but I would have expected it to use either the `subscribeOn()` scheduler or the `observeOn` scheduler. So what does it use and is there an elegant way of controlling which thread it is executed on?

Comment: It runs on the caller thread which called `dispose()`. The [unsubscribeOn()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#unsubscribeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-) operator switches the thread for the dispose calls going upstream.

Comment: Ok, so I should add `.unsubscribeOn(mainScheduler)` _before_ the `.doOnDispose()` call?

Comment: More digging tells me the `.unsubscribeOn()` call should go _after_ the `.doOnDispose()` as it affects upstream operations. The javadoc could perhaps be more explicit about that.

Comment: You are welcome to contribute to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question was asked more than 3 years ago, let me contribute because I just encountered a similar issue.

```
package com.example.sample4

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var disposable: Disposable

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.start).setOnClickListener {
            disposable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap { i ->
                    Observable.fromCallable {
                        Thread.sleep(1_000L)
                        if (i == 3) {
                            disposable.dispose()
                        }
                        i
                    }
                }
                .map { it * 2 }
                .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
                .doOnNext {
                    Log.d("SampleApp", "val=$it on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                }
                .doOnDispose {
                    Log.d("SampleApp", "disposed on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                }
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe {
                    println(it)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

```
2022-01-17 16:34:35.585 27458-27505/com.example.sample4 D/SampleApp: val=2 on RxSingleScheduler-1
2022-01-17 16:34:36.587 27458-27505/com.example.sample4 D/SampleApp: val=4 on RxSingleScheduler-1
2022-01-17 16:34:37.590 27458-27505/com.example.sample4 D/SampleApp: val=6 on RxSingleScheduler-1
2022-01-17 16:34:37.590 27458-27506/com.example.sample4 D/SampleApp: disposed on RxComputationThreadPool-1
```

As you can see, the scheduler used in `doOnDispose` is provided in `unsubscribeOn`. **And it's important to put unsubscribeOn last.**